# проблема с установкой WSL 2 для Docker

Tags: windows, docker, wsl2

При установке WSL 2 и включений - Hyper-V, Платформа виртуальной машины на windows 11 22H2 pro. Установка происходи без ошибок, все в штатном режиме. После просит перезагрузить машину.
При перезагрузке, пишет, про обновление, доходит до 30%, перезагружает.
Идет стартовый экран, с возможностью зайти в BIOS. И после черный экран, и все. Кулеры молотят, но ни чего не меняется.  Захожу через безопасный режим, он автоматически сносит установку WSL 2 и выключает  Hyper-V и Платформа виртуальной машины.
В чем может быть проблема? Ноутбук asus Модель TUF Gaming FX505DV.
В Bios Виртуализация включена.
.